# Can I call a prop like this? If not then how can i do this dynamically

Tags: c#

```
Class1 n = new Class1 { Id = 1, 
                        Name="salis", city="KhANPUR", email="ASDASDASDA" };

foreach (var fieldInfo in n.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var propName = fieldInfo.Name;
    Console.WriteLine(n.propName);
}
```

I know it throws an exception and my code is bad.

Kindly help this how I can do this

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Doesn't even compile since `Class1` doesn't have a member named `propName`.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to compile I noticed that.

Comment: Also, what object is `m` supposed to be?

Comment: @seairth its `n` not `m` i just correct it its my fault

Comment: @SalisTariq It looks like there are already a couple of answers, one of which appears to thoroughly answer your question.  If those aren't correct, you need to update your original question to more clearly explain the problem you are having.  Including the definition of `Class1` and the desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.GetValue(n));
```

Answer (score 1):

complete compilable version:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication99
{
  class Program
  {
    class Class1
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string city { get; set; }
      public string email { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Class1 n = new Class1 { Id = 1, Name = "salis", city = "KhANPUR", email = "ASDASDASDA" };

      foreach (var fieldInfo in n.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
        var propName = fieldInfo.Name;
        var propValue = fieldInfo.GetValue(n);
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}: {1}", propName, propValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

results:

```
Id   : 1
Name : salis
city : KhANPUR
email: ASDASDASDA
```

Comment: i also print the name of properties i want to use it with a object like Class1 n = new Class1();
n.propName;

Comment: I do not know exactly what you mean. What a name in n.proName supposed to be displayed? Id, Name, city, email... ?

Comment: it will be inside the `foreach` loop
when propname = city then i want `n.city` and when propname = email then i want `n.email`

Comment: `.GetType().GetProperties()` uses Reflections to get values and names from unknown classes. The `n.city` is a direct access on a known property and does not require a reflections loop. i have updated the code to print names and the values.